# Route all page requests to one class in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make an application that can host multiple ecommerce front ends, so I need to figure out how to route all requests to one class which then parses templates and handles all output.

So my question is then how do I route all requests to one class?

In PHP I would use mod_rewrite and have all requests go to index.php and add "main = new MainClass();", but I have no idea on how to achieve this with ASP.NET

The MVC framework isn't what I'm looking for, since I will host several domains with one system.

Comment: "The MVC framework isn't what I'm looking for, since I will host several domains with one system." - I'm not sure that means what you think it means...

Comment: I realize that I'm bad at describing this. It's because I have very little experience with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is an [HttpModule](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net%20httpmodule).  (Sorry for the Google link, but there's a *lot* about this out there and I'm not sure which is the best resource for you.)

Essentially, what an HttpModule does is intercept requests between the web server (IIS) and the application (ASP.NET).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Route` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.aspx) to register route handlers for all of the routes you define.  Basically, you would create one instance of an implementation of [`IRouteHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.aspx) (or different instances of the same type) for all the permutations of the urls on your site.

Also, it should be said that following statement that you made is misguided:

> The MVC framework isn't what I'm
>   looking for, since I will host several
>   domains with one system.

Any problems or limitations you would run into hosting several domains in one system with MVC will be apparent in ASP.NET as well; MVC sits on top of ASP.NET, not separate from it.

Comment: It's not hosting several domains that is the issue, it's every single domain having their own templates for certain areas of the site that is the problem.

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen: You should see @David comment on your question, I believe he is right.

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen: Is each site going to be its own web application, or all shared within a single application?  If the former, each having its own design is trivial.  If the latter, it's just a matter of how you'd define that design.  Maybe put each one in its own directory hierarchy with its own CSS, images, even config.  Maybe have a conditional around the loading of CSS to load specific ones based on some server condition.  Etc.  There's nothing inherent in the MVC Framework that prevents hosting multiple websites.

Comment: They will all be hosted by the same application. They will all have basically the same html-code, but will use different css-files. The problem with the MVC is that views doesn't really do what I want, but I will probably use it anyway. Instead of different templates I might just pass some settings to the view to show/hide certain elements.